# Find sharepoint workflow in site collection

Tags: workflow

Is there any way to check if there is any workflow either out of box or designer under any site collection. The issue is there are many list, library and site under a site collection and it is very time cosuming to check every list manually whether workflow is associated with it. Is there any alternative for the same using powershell or any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be what you are looking for, a powershell script that return the names of all workflows that are used within your SharePoint farm.

http://sharepointrelated.com/tag/get-spworkflow/

You should be able to scope it to a specific site collection by replacing

```
   "Get-SPSite -Limit All"
```

to

```
   "Get-SPSite http://YourServer/Sites/YourSiteColl"
```

in

```
   #Grab all webs
   Get-SPSite -Limit All | % {$webs += $_.Allwebs}
   if($webs.count -ge 1)
   {
   foreach($web in $webs)
   {
```

Best of luck!